# FOSUserBundle BCryptPasswordEncoder salting

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, bcrypt, password-hash

After an upgrade to php7, the BCryptPasswordEncoder throws the following error, e.g. on registration when using FOSUserBundle standard registration page:

> "Use of the 'salt' option to password_hash is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\ascentary
>   \vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder.php line 81
>   " at C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler."

I've tracked down this issue, and the problem is the FOS UserManager class, that calls:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function updatePassword(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (0 !== strlen($password = $user->getPlainPassword())) {
        $encoder = $this->getEncoder($user);
        $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt()));
        $user->eraseCredentials();
    }
}
```

Passing here $user->getSalt() throws the error, because at php7, you are not allowed anymore to pass a custom salt to bcrypt encoding / password_hash function. In addition, I see a problem in the base fos user entity, because in its constructor, the salt is set like:

```
$this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
```

Questions:

(1) How to solve the error I posted above? Maybe overriding the UserManager, or is there a solution provided by fos?

(2) How to properly safe the salt, that is automatically being generated?

(3) Are there any other updates required, like updating the ircmaxell lib?

Comment: [bcrypt is not an encryption algorithm](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded)

Comment: Thanks, nice article!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Symfony3.

`BCryptPasswordEncoder.php` line 75:

```
if ($salt) {
    // Ignore $salt, the auto-generated one is always the best
}
```

Comment: I cannot upgrade because a lot of other composer packages depend on symfony 2.X, like Sonata project. Most of the packages are not yet upgraded to Work with symfony3

Comment: So you can try to set user salt to null in user entity/document.

Comment: Also thought about that but then the salt would always be null and I could not save / use the Auto generated one again. See Nr 2)

Comment: From Symfony cookbook: __"Do you need to a Salt property?

If you use bcrypt, no. Otherwise, yes. All passwords must be hashed with a salt, but bcrypt does this internally. Since this tutorial does use bcrypt, the getSalt() method in User can just return null (it's not used). If you use a different algorithm, you'll need to uncomment the salt lines in the User entity and add a persisted salt property.
"__

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I have one further thought: when it crashes at this point, will it also crash at other points due to php7?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think symfony on its own will not crash, but the other packages can contain deprecated code.

Comment: So would you wait upgrading to php7 and use php5.6 until all packages got updated?

Comment: I already switched to php7 and build new apps on it, but I keep the old on php5 until I'll test it all :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set $salt attribute is null by overriding **FOS\UserBundle\Model\User**

```
namespace YourNamespace\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourNamespace\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
            @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *              name="salt",
 *              column=@ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", nullable=true)
 *          )
 *     })
 *
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->salt = null;
    }

    //another codes
}
```